# Triangulable linear transformation restricted to an invariant vector space is triangulable

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, triangulation

Suppose $V$ is a vector space of finite dimension and $f:V \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation which is triangulable. If $W$ is an $f$-invariant subspace of $V$, show that $f \mid _W$ is also triangulable.

Comment: Does triangulable just mean similar to a triangular matrix?

Comment: @BadamBaplan it means there exists a vector basis in which the matrix is triangular (upper). I think it's the same

Comment: What are your tries?

Comment: @Azif00 I proved it for diagonalizable matrices, by saying that the eigenvalues of restricted f are a subset of the eigenvalues of f but it doesn't work here, I can't think of anything else in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a matrix is triangulabe, what you can say about it's characteristic polynomial?
Then what is the relationship between characteristic polynomial of $f$ and the characteristic polynomial of $f_{\mid W}$?

Comment: if a matrix is triangulable, you can write its characteristic polynomial as the product of first-degree factors, and the characteristic polynomial of f|W divides the characteristic polynomial of f

Comment: so f|W is also triangulable, and that's it?

Comment: yes $f\mid W$ is triangulable because f triangulable <=> its characteristic polynomial splits

Comment: okay this seems enough. thanks!